# calling a function to do another task

Tags: java, function

im calling a function to help work out a second calculation but it complies but dosnt return correct answer

tired a few different things but breaks codes so more then likely completely wrong 
     9. This question involves writing two functions. 
a.  The interest on a loan is currently 2.4% (0.024). If you take a £9000 
    loan to day you will pay 9000 * 0.024 ( £216) for a year. Start by writing a 
    function called calculateInterest which takes the loanAmount 
    (which can be any number not just 9000) as a float and a second argument 
    interestRate (also float can be any faction) which is the interest rate 
    for the loan. It should return a float which is the Interest (£216 in the 
    example above).
b.  When calculateInterest works write a function called HW2I. (I=capital i)
    This takes 2 float arguments. The original loan amount (float) and years 
    (an int) which is the number of years the loan will operate over (say 35). 
    Each year the interest is calculated (via a call to the calculateInterest 
    function). Interest is then added to the loan amount. This value (loan+
    interest) is the new loan amount. Write the function HW2I.  Don’t forget to
    test it yourself to make sure it works correctly. Here is the pseudo code.

```
To HW2I ( loan, intreastRate , years )
    Repeat with year = 1 to years 
       adjustedLoan = loan + calculateInterest( loan , intreastRate )
       loan = adjustedLoan
    end repeat 
 return loan 



public float calculateInterest(float loanAmount, float interestRate) {
    float intrest;
    intrest = loanAmount * interestRate;
    return intrest;
}

public float HW2I(float loan, int years) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= years; i = i++) {
        loan = loan + calculateInterest(9000, 0.24);
    }
    return (loan);
}
```

Comment: From Review: Unfortunately, questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because they address mostly the business logic instead of isolated programming issues.

Comment: You are passing an interest rate of 24%  (`0.24`) in your `calculateInterest` call.  Maybe you meant to write `0.024` (2.4%) instead?  Otherwise, everything looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we go to the same university because I have the exact same question so here's the answer:

```
public float calculateInterest(float loanAmount, float interestRate) {
    float interest = (loanAmount * interestRate);
    {
        return interest;
    }
}

public float HW2I(float loanAmount, float interestRate, int years) {
    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        float newLoanAmount = loanAmount + calculateInterest(loanAmount, interestRate);
        loanAmount = newLoanAmount;
    }
    return loanAmount;
}
```

Good luck!

For the explanation:

The first method only asks us to calculate the *interest*, which is done by multiplying the *loanAmount* and the *interestRate* together. After, we return the *interest*.

For the second function, the pseudo code shows us that we need 3 arguments, which are *float loanAmount*, *float interestRate* and *int years*. It also says "Repeat with year= 1 to years" meaning we need to use iteration, so we do the *for(int i= 0; i< years; i++* part. If we look back at the question we need a **newLoanAmount** which is the first *loanAmount* + a call to the first method, which is *calculateInterest(loanAmount, interestRate)*. Now the *loanAmount* becomes the *newLoanAmount*, kind of replacing the value of the *loanAmount* before. Because the value has changed, we need to return *loanAmount*.

I hope this helps further and apologises if it isn't a great explanation; I started learning Java 2 months ago.